# Multiple forms for one model in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have an app where people can submit information for various offers listed on the website.

Lets say offer A only requires you to submit a first and last name, but offer B requires a first, last, and phone number.

I have a 'submission' model that has all of these fields available. What is the best way to present this in a form.

If a person clicks on offer A, they should see a form that only has first and last.  If they click on offer B, they should see a form that has first, last and phone number.

Obviously this is a very simple example of what I'm trying to accomplish.  Ideally, there could be hundreds or thousands of offers and the 'submission' form would need to be different depending on which offer was chosen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

each offer needs to have a set of tags indicating the required fields.

this could easily be stored as a serialized string representing a simple json array [:name, :phone_number, ....]  etc.

Include this field in the view, and only display fields if they are in the required_fields array.

If you want to dynamically change the offer without reloading the page then you will send all fields, but as you change offers use jQuery to hide the fields that are not required.

If you do want a no-page update type solution I highly recommend you investigate react.rb (http://reactrb.org)  but if you are looking to have the page be refreshed when the offer changes then just do it all in the view logic.

Here is some rough code outlines:

```
class Offer < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :required_fields # will be an array of tags - there are also nice gems for this too
end


# in your view file
# assume a variable field is in a loop generating each field then:
  <% if @offer.required_fields.include? field %>
    <!-- generate the field -->
  <% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

To add to `Mitch`'s suggestion, you must be aware that each model will include an [`attributes` method](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/attributes), which will allow you to loop through the `Model`'s attributes:

```
@offer.attributes.each do |field|
   # if field is required
end
```

What you could do is mix this with `Mitch`'s answer, however, you'll want to create a separate attribute in your table called `required` or something. This should be the equivalent of a hash, and allow you to store what `Mitch` suggested for each record:

```
#app/views/offer/show.html.erb
<%= form_for @offer do |f| %>
   <% @offer.attributes.each do |field| %>
      <% f.text_field field.to_sym if @offer.required.includes?(field) %>
   <% end %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

You'd be able to store the `required` field as some sort of `key:value` pair; notably the `hstore` field type in `PGSQL`, or just a `longtext` to store it in `MYSQL`.

Comment: Rich great clarification!